# ReactJS with Firebase, also using React Redux for login of user and how for the admin

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-saga

The code below is the login output wherein the user and the admin use it as the entry way into the website. There is no problem to the logging in of the user and the admin but the only problem is how to redirect the admin after the login to the website which will redirect to the admin dashboard home?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  emailSignInStart,
  googleSignInStart,
} from "./../../Redux/User/user.actions";

import "./style.scss";

import ButtonForm from "./../Forms/Button";

import {


Typography,
  Divider,
  IconButton,
  TextField,
  Tooltip,
} from "@material-ui/core";

import { FaFacebook, FaGoogle, FaMailBulk } from "react-icons/fa";
import Visibility from "@material-ui/icons/Visibility";
import VisibilityOff from "@material-ui/icons/VisibilityOff";

const mapState = ({ user }) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser,
}); //to get from the redux store

const SigninIn = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();
  const { currentUser } = useSelector(mapState);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    //whenever signinsuccess is true
    if (currentUser) {
      resetForm();
      history.push("/");
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [currentUser]);

  const resetForm = () => {
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
    setErrors([]);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(emailSignInStart({ email, password }));
    setIsLoading(true);
  };

  const handleGoogleSignIn = () => {
    dispatch(googleSignInStart());
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="wrap">
        <h2>Log in</h2>
        <div className="formWrap">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="grouped">
              <TextField
                autoFocus
                margin="dense"
                type="email"
                label="Email"
                color="secondary"
                fullWidth
                variant="outlined"
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
              <br></br>

              {/* {Might use this for password validation - https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-password-field} */}

              <TextField
                margin="dense"
                type="password"
                label="Password"
                fullWidth
                color="secondary"
                variant="outlined"
                helperText="Password must be more than 6 characters long"
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                required
              />

              <Link to="/recovery">
                <Typography align="center" variant="subtitle1" display="block">
                  Forgot Password?
                </Typography>
              </Link>

              <br></br>
              <ButtonForm type="submit" className="btn">
                {isLoading ? (
                  <p>
                    {" "}
                    <Typography variant="h6" align="center" 
                          display="block">
                      Logging In...
                    </Typography>
                  </p>
                ) : (
                  <Typography variant="h6" align="center" display="block">
                    Log In
                  </Typography>
                )}
              </ButtonForm>

              <br></br>
              <Divider />
              <Typography variant="subtitle2" align="center" display="block">
                Or Continue with
              </Typography>

              <div className="socialSignin">
                <div className="row">
                  <Tooltip title="Continue with Google">
                    <IconButton
                      onClick={handleGoogleSignIn}
                      aria-label="googleSignIn"
                    >
                      <FaGoogle
                        style={{
                          color: "#EA4335",
                          fontSize: "30px",
                        }}
                      />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Tooltip>

                  <Tooltip title="Register with email">
                    <Link to="/registration">
                      <IconButton aria-label="mailRegister">
                        <FaMailBulk
                          style={{
                            color: "#e31837",
                            fontSize: "30px",
                          }}
                        />
                      </IconButton>
                    </Link>
                  </Tooltip>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SigninIn;
```

How can I solve it into making the redirecting of the page after login directly to the admin page? How can I do it with some use of React Router, React Redux and other parts of ReactJS wherein that it will redirect the admin directly to the page of the admin as a landing page.

Comment: What way, if any, does the app have to differentiate admin users from basic users? That could be useful.

Comment: The app does have that, the admin can login and be redirected also to the User homepage. But it doesn't redirect the admin automatically to the admin dashboard page once the admin logs into the wesbite. There is an admin option on nav of the user if the admin is the one who logs in. That is how an admin user can access the admin dashboard instead of directly leading it into the admin dashboard.

Comment: Where is this redirect to the user homepage? Why can't it redirect to a different target page? What have you tried? Have you included all relevant code in your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How do you know an admin user has logged in? What differentiates them from regular users?